# awk file manipulation

Tags: perl, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have the following words on my text file and I want extract as follow.

```
device1 te rfe3 -1     10.1.2.3   device1 te rfe3
device2 cdr thr        10.2.5.3   device2 cdr thr
device4                10.6.0.8   device4
device3 hrdnsrc dhe    10.8.3.6   device3 hrdnsrc dhe
```

my objective is to extract the device name and the ip adrress everything else to strip away. 
the is no pattern after device name some of them has 2-3 word some of them does not have any thing. also I don't need the 3rd column. I am looking the result like this.

```
device1   10.1.2.3
device2   10.2.5.3 
device3   10.8.3.6 
device3   10.8.9.4
```

is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 sed -r 's/^([^ ]*) .* (([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}).*$/\1 \2/'
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ sed -r 's/^([^ ]*) .* (([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}).*$/\1 \2/' ./infile
device1 10.1.2.3

device2 10.2.5.3

device4 10.6.0.8

device3 10.8.3.6
```

Answer (score 3):

In `awk`, this is something like

```
$ awk '{
         for (f = 2; f <= NF; f++) {
           if ($f ~ /^([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+$/) {
             print $1, $f
             break
           }
         }
       }' file
```

---

Here's a transcript:

```
mress:10192 Z$ cat pffft.awk
{
  for (f = 2; f <= NF; f++) {
    if ($f ~ /^([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+$/) {
      print $1, $f
      break
    }
  }
}
mress:10193 Z$ cat pfft.in 
device1 te rfe3 -1     10.1.2.3   device1 te rfe3
device2 cdr thr        10.2.5.3   device2 cdr thr
device4                10.6.0.8   device4
device3 hrdnsrc dhe    10.8.3.6   device3 hrdnsrc dhe
mress:10194 Z$ awk -f pffft.awk pfft.in
device1 10.1.2.3
device2 10.2.5.3
device4 10.6.0.8
device3 10.8.3.6
mress:10195 Z$ _
```

Comment: I am having trouble interpreting that response.

Comment: @dan: awk will not change the file.  It reads text from the file and writes it to standard output.  To update the file, redirect output with something like `awk '...' file > file2`.  Do **not** use the same file for input and output, because the OS will truncate the file as soon as it opens it for writing.

Comment: I did copy and paste each your commands except (>) and at the end I did myFile > myFile2 and the result on the out put file is 0. did I miss anything? I have never use multi line awk command before may be I missed something. thank you Sir!!!

Comment: You may have missed something. I'll edit with something more useful; for some reason I completely spaced on my example not being cut-and-paste-able.

Comment: I think you have an extra `+` there, `[0-9]++$` should be `[0-9]+$`, yes?

Comment: *sigh* yes, for some reason the `+` vanished the first time so I added it back in and now it's doubled.  weirdness?  also lost a backslash but that one's easier to understand.  Edited.

Answer (score 3):

in perl

```
perl -ne 'next if /^\s*$/ ; /^(\w+).*?(\d+(\.\d+){3})/; print "$1\t$2\n"' test_file
```

for sorted results you could probably pipe the output to sort command

```
perl -ne 'next if /^\s*$/ ; /^(\w+).*?(\d+(\.\d+){3})/; print "$1\t$2\n"' test_file | sort
```

Updated script like version

```
my $test_file = shift or die "no input file provided\n";

# open a filehandle to your test file
open my $fh, '<', $test_file or die "could not open $test_file: $!\n";

while (<$fh>) {
    # ignore the blank lines
    next if /^\s*$/;

    # regex matching
    /               # regex starts
    ^               # beginning of the string
    (\w+)           # store the first word in $1
    \s+             # followed by a space
    .*?             # match anything but don't be greedy until...
    (\d+(\.\d+){3}) # expands to (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) and stored in $2
    /x;             # regex ends 

    # print first and second match
    print "$1\t$2\n"
}
```

Comment: Awesome! this is working perfectly on command line,so I want include on my perl script. how is that work inside the script. any idea!!! thank you so very much

Answer (score 1):

Python's not on your list, but something like this might work.

```
import sys
import re
pattern= re.compile( "^(\w+)\s.*?\s(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s.*$" )
for line in sys.stdin:
    match= pattern.match( line )
    sys.stdout.write( "{0} {1}".format( match.group(1), match.group(2) ) )
```

It should work on most Linux platforms, since Python is already installed.

Comment: no clue how it's work. add your command on linux command line? or create as script and run. would you tell me how? thanks again!

Comment: The pattern should be "^(\w+)\s.*?\s(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s" and the groups to print "match.group(1), match.group(2)".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input file has the fields always aligned to the same columns, the shortest POSIX solution would be

```
$ cut -c1-8,23-33 x
device1  10.1.2.3

device2  10.2.5.3

device4  10.6.0.8

device3  10.8.3.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how close to an IP number the cruft get, this may or may not cat your cake:

```
sed -re 's/^([^ ]*).* ([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}).*/\1 \2/g'
```

Comment: nothing happen on the command. thanks for your response though.

Answer (score 0):

À la the `cut` solution with perl you could use "unpack" if the file is always in the same format column wise:

```
perl -nE 'say unpack("A8 x14 A9")' data.txt
```

Or use a regular expression to get the first word followed by a space `^(\w+\s)` and then one or more digits following a `.` 3 times `(\d+(\.\d+){3})`:

```
perl -nE '/^(?<name>\w+\s).*?(?<ip>\d+(\.\d+){3})/; 
         say "$+{name} $+{ip}" '  data.txt
```

The named captures (`$+{name} $+{ip}`) are just for fun :-)